# Detecting a TCP reset with Linux sockets

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

When one end of a TCP link disconnects, it sends a reset (RST) message to the other end. I want to be able to receive this in the application layer.

In my code, I use a `select()` call to receive input from potentially multiple sources, including a TCP connection. I've seen that when the [`select()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select) shows that there is data ready to read on the connection, and then a [`read()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/read) call returns 0 bytes read, that happened after a RST was sent over TCP. (I understand [`recv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) works similarly to `read()`.)

**Does `read()` return 0 bytes (after `select()`) on a TCP connection only if the connection was reset? Does it ever return 0 bytes in any other cases?**

I remember a while ago using a particular ethernet device on the other end of the connection, and this Linux end was receiving 0 bytes after a `select()`, but not for a connection reset, but rather mid-way through some data streaming. I confirmed in Wireshark that the packet received had 0 data bytes. Is this a bug, or like the question above, is it valid to have this behaviour? I can't remember which device it was, as it was a few years back, but it was using a Windows driver.

Comment: Note that one should read the question I was intending by mentally replacing "reset/RST" with "finish/FIN". I screwed up the question when I wrote it.

Comment: Well then simple, you read 0 bytes from the socket if the peer has closed its connection using a normal close. This is the peer saying I will no longer send anything to you and it is called a half close.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> When one end of a TCP link disconnects, it sends a reset (RST) message to the other end.

Not normally.

> I want to be able to receive this in the application layer.

You will.

> I've seen that when the select() shows that there is data ready to read on the connection, and then a read() call returns 0 bytes read, that happened after a RST was sent over TCP.

No.

> Does read() return 0 bytes (after select()) on a TCP connection only if the connection was reset?

**Never** if the connection was reset. It returns -1 with `errno == ECONNRESET` in that case.

> Does it ever return 0 bytes in any other cases?

It returns zero if and only if a FIN was received, i.e. the peer closed the connection, or shutdown his socket for output.

Comment: If you repeat one of the reads above you will get the same result again. So don't. You should have closed the socket the first time you got either 0 or -1, with the sole exeception of a read timeout (-1/EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK).

Comment: Oops, that's what I get for writing a question a long time after last seeing a Wireshark trace! I was meaning FIN where I said RST - just mentally substitute it in. That completely screwed up the question.
So the last line is the pertinent one - I assume the conclusion there is that the aforementioned Windows driver was buggy.

Comment: @JetskiS-type You can receive 0 bytes in UDP, not in TCP. I've used every version of Windows since 2.x and I've never seen a TCP `recv()` return zero in mid-stream.

Comment: Okay, good. It was just this one ethernet device/driver that I've seen it on, and I no longer user that device, so I don't need to worry about seeing it mid-stream again then.

Answer (score 0):

You also get a RST if you try to connect to a port at a server for which there is no listener.

Suppose you have a connection to a server and send data to it regularly, but then the server reboots, your socket pair does not exist anymore of course and then you also get a RST.

It is possible for a server to send a RST, by using socket options I believe, but this is not a good idea, servers/clients should use a normal close on a socket in normal situations where they want to close the communication, and let TCP's 4 way handshake do its thing.

Comment: Thanks, but I screwed up the question and said RST instead of FIN... :\